# Scope/order of evaluation of nested `let .. in ..` in OCaml

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml, evaluation, let

I have a little problems here that I don't 100% understand:

`let x = 1 in let x = x+2 in let x = x+3 in x`

I know the result of this expression is 6, but just want to make sure the order of calculating this expression; which part is calculated first?

Comment: FYI, there are no closures involved in this code. This is just about variable scope.

Comment: Since this is a pure expression, the order of evaluation has no visible effect.  Since OCaml does have imperative features, however, the order of evaluation for `let v = e1 in e2` is specified: the expression `e1` is evaluated first, then `e2`.  As Chuck says, your example seems harder than it is because you use the same name several times.  This doesn't affect anything other than how easy it is to understand.  You could always use 3 different variable names.

Comment: Same as `let x = 1 in let y = x+2 in let z = y+3 in z`

Comment: (Yes, exactly!  We even used the same variable names.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You asked about the *order* of the evaluation in the expression `let x=1 in let x=x+2 in ...`. The order is "left-to-right"! When you have a chain of `let a=b in let c=d in ...`, the order of evaluation is always left-to-right.

However, in your example there is a confusing part: you used the *same* variable name, `x`, in every `let` construct. This is confusing because you then see things like `let x=x+1`, and this looks like you are "redefining" `x` or "changing the value of `x`". But no "changing" of "x" actually happens here in OCAML! What happens here, as already pointed out above, is that a *new variable* is introduced every time, so your example is entirely equivalent to

```
 let x = 1 in let y = x+2 in let z = y+3 in z;;
```

Note that here the order of evaluation is also left-to-right. (It is always left-to-right in every chain of `let` constructs.) In your original question, you chose to call all these new variables "x" rather than `x`, `y`, and `z`. This is confusing to most people. It is better to avoid this kind of coding style.

But how do we check that we renamed the variables correctly? Why "let x=1 in let y=x+2" and not "let x=1 in let x=y+2"? This `x=x+2` business is quite confusing! Well, there is another way of understanding the evaluation of `let x=aaa in bbb`. The construct

```
  let x=aaa in bbb
```

can be always replaced by the following closure applied to `aaa`,

```
  (fun x -> bbb) aaa
```

Once you rewrite it in this way, you can easily see two things: First, OCAML will not evaluate "bbb" inside the closure until "aaa" is evaluated. (For this reason, the evaluation of `let x=aaa in bbb` proceeds by first evaluating `aaa` and then `bbb`, that is, "left-to-right".) Second, the variable "x" is confined to the body of the closure and so "x" cannot be visible inside the expression "aaa". For this reason, if "aaa" contains a variable called "x", it must be already defined with some value before, and it has nothing to do with the "x" inside the closure. For reasons of clarity, it would be better to call this variable by a different name.

In your example:

```
 let x=1 in let x=x+2 in let x=x+3 in x
```

is rewritten as

```
 (fun x -> let x=x+2 in let x=x+3 in x) 1
```

Then the inner `let` constructs are also rewritten:

```
 (fun x -> (fun x -> let x=x+3 in x) x+2 ) 1
 (fun x -> (fun x -> (fun x-> x) x+3) x+2 ) 1
```

Now let us rename the arguments of functions inside each function, which we can always do without changing the meaning of the code:

```
 (fun x -> (fun y -> (fun z -> z) y+3) x+2 ) 1
```

This is the same as

```
 let x=1 in let y=x+2 in let z=y+3 in z
```

In this way, you can verify that you have renamed the variables correctly.

Answer (score 4):

Imagine parens:

```
let x = 1 in (let x = (x+2) in (let x = (x+3) in x))
```

Then substitute (x=1) where x it's not covered by another declaration of x and eliminate outermost `let`:

```
let x = (1+2) in (let x = (x+3) in x)
```

Evaluate:

```
let x = 3 in (let x = (x+3) in x)
```

Substitute:

```
let x = (3+3) in x
```

Evaluate:

```
let x = 6 in x
```

Substitute:

```
6
```

Answer (score 4):

(This is a little long for a comment, so here's a smallish extra answer.)

As Chuck points out, there is no closure involved in this expression.  The only complexity at all is due to the scoping rules.  OCaml scoping rules are the usual ones, i.e., names refer to the nearest (innermost) definition.  In the expression:

```
let v = e1 in e2
```

The variable `v` isn't visible (i.e., cannot be named) in `e1`.  If (by chance) a variable of that name appears in `e1`, it must refer to some outer definition of (a different) `v`.  But the new `v` can (of course) be named in `e2`.  So your expression is equivalent to the following:

```
let x = 1 in let y = x+2 in let z = y+3 in z
```

It seems to me this is clearer, but it has exactly the same meaning.